# How to add the column to entity that take default value according to another entity column in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, enums, typeorm

I want add a new column to my entity that will check another entity column and accordingly will set the default value. I want to show it in example

```js
export enum TaskStatus {
  OPEN = 'open',
  CLOSED = 'closed',
}

export class TaskEntity extends AbstractEntity {

  @Column(enumColumn(TaskStatus, { nullable: true }))
  status?: TaskStatus;


  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description?: string;
}
```

I want to check if the status is **open**, when it is **open**, I want to add a new column that will have **dueDate**, because the closed task will not have any **due date**. How can I update my new entity and then run the migration?

Comment: You **cannot** do that. The column is either there for every row or it is not there for every row.  What you need is to define the column as allowing nulls. Then when inserting or updating set the column to `null` of the specified value as appropriate. You can *automate* setting in trigger(s) as necessary.